# Way to restrict domain URLs in Marketing Cloud Einstein Web Recommendations tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

We have few websites with Einstein Web Recommendations tracking scripts set up. Is there a way on MC side, without deleting a script from websites, to restrict tracked domain URLs only to certain ones, like it can be done with Google Analytics in Journey settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collect code is all configured within the website outside of SFMC

If you don't want the collect to track on a web page don't install the collect code on that web page.

Only install it on the pages where you want it to fire. Various tag managers should be able to accomplish this as needed.